# How can I extract .bin (image) files?

Tags: file-format

I need to extract a .bin file and I have no idea how to do it in Ubuntu. In Windows I usually used to do it using MagicISO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [acetoneiso](http://packages.ubuntu.com/acetoneiso) [image: Install acetoneiso]

Is a feature-rich and complete software application to manage CD/DVD images. Thanks to powerful open source tools such as fuseiso, AcetoneISO will let You mount typical proprietary images formats of the Windows world such as ISO BIN NRG MDF IMG and do plenty of other things.

```
sudo apt-get install acetoneiso
```

Answer (score 7):

## [bchunk](http://packages.ubuntu.com/bchunk) [image: Install bchunk]

binchunker converts a CD image in a ".bin / .cue" format (sometimes ".raw / .cue") to a set of .iso and .cdr tracks. The bin/cue format is used by some popular non-Unix cd-writing software, but is not supported on most other CD burning programs. A lot of CD/VCD images distributed on the Internet are in BIN/CUE format.

```
sudo apt-get install bchunk

bchunk <image.bin> <image.cue> <basename>
sudo mount -o loop basename.iso /mnt
sudo ls /mnt
```

Comment: It is not working, i installed bchunk, and run this command: (bchunk test.bin test)
(sudo mount -o loop test.iso /mnt)

but it give me the following error:
( test.iso: No such file or directory )

Comment: @sctz i tested by myself but bchunk need two file *.bin and *.cue try with acetoneiso it work well too

Comment: After running the bchunk <image.bin> <image.cue> <basename> command you can double click on the iso image to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [fuseiso](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FuseISO):

```
sudo apt install fuseiso

fuseiso file.bin mount_directory
```

If successful, when you open the mount point (`mount_directory`), you should see the contents of the file.